# Hibernate raising "NullPointerException" on when setting a parameter to a @Filter

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am having a very weird problem. I am using Hibernate 4.1.7 with Postgres 9.1. In my entity class I defined a filter using annotation:

```
@FilterDef(name = "filterName", parameters=@ParamDef(name="paramInt", type="integer" ))
```

Then I added the @Filter to the collection. If the filter is defined this way:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "linkField")
@Filter(name = "filterName", condition = "fieldVal=0")
private Collection<ChildClass> children;
```

Everything works properly, the collection is properly filtered and I see only the children whose fieldVal is 0. If, on the other hand, I do:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "linkField")
@Filter(name = "filterName", condition = "fieldVal=:paramInt")
private Collection<ChildClass> children;
```

and I set the parameter in my code, the "filter" is properly set (inspecting it in the debugger) but, when accessing the collection, it raises the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.QueryParameters.processFilters(QueryParameters.java:492)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.QueryParameters.processFilters(QueryParameters.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1688)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:832)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2094)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1801)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:524)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:242)
```

I am out of ideas, I have been trying to figure out what it can be for days, searched everywhere to no avail. Anybody has a clue on what can be?

Thanks!

Edited: made more clear when the exception was raised

Answer (score 1):

Ok it was TOTALLY my fault even if the documentation was not crystal clear about this.

You can indeed pass variables via annotations but the problem was in the name of the filter. I simplified too much in my example (hence my fault) and used a different filter name. You cannot name a filter with the same strategy you adopt maybe for named queries (i.e. class.filtername) because doing so Hibernate will "split" the filter and get only the part before the dot. Hence the filter does not exist, resulting in the above mentioned exception.

My filter line was:

```
@Filter(name = "className.filterName", condition = "fieldVal=:value")
```

and that raised the exception because Hibernate, in processing the filter at line 492 of QueryParameters.java, split filter name and looked ONLY for a filter called className. Changing it to:

```
@Filter(name = "filterName", condition = "fieldVal=:value")
```

works properly.